# How to fix keyboard's media keys?

Tags: release-juno, keyboard

Sometimes after I login to my system the media keys are dead. If I logout and back in, they usually work again.

Any way fix this permanently, or at least without having to do a relog?

I'm running 5.0 Juno.

---

As pointed out by CameronNemo, the gnome-settings-daemon handles media key presses.
After running `exec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys` my media keys started working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-settings-daemon handles media key presses. Perhaps it is either being started too early or too late. Your best bet is to try and isolate the problem to this service by stopping and starting it again (without logging out and in).

Comment: As pointed out by CameronNemo, the gnome-settings-daemon handles media key presses. After running exec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys my media keys started working again.

Comment: Can you share the name of the service in order to stop/start/restart it?